# Remove N/A from all formula calculations in all tabs of a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with many (more than 50) tabs with different formula calculations. In some cells there are N/A as an output. The sheet is old an managed by different team members, so i can't manage it to edit every formula.

How can i remove N/A from all tabs, from the whole sheet?

I've seen many similar topics here, but all of them deal with a single formula on the level of editing of it with `IFERROR` or `IFNA` or similar - i will just not get it manually in the whole sheet. And i can't use search and replace - all formulas are different, so i can't just add `=IFNA(`.

Comment: use ctrl+H tick formulas and regex and replace ^= with =IFNA(

Comment: @player0 There are some `VLOOKUP` too - how can i catch N/A there with your method?

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to do with `Apps Script`

Here is a working snippet which **replaces** all N/A found in formulas in every sheet to ""

```js
function replaceFormulaInSheets() {

  var textToReplace = "N/A";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();

  for(var k in sheets){

    var sheet = sheets[k];
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();

    for (var i in formulas) {

      for (var j in formulas[i]){

        formulas[i][j] = formulas[i][j].replace(textToReplace, "");

      }

    }

    range.setFormulas(formulas);

  }
}
```